# Can someone help me understand「どころの話ではない」in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, particles

I don't think I really get it. Could someone please help me?

> 倍返しどころの話ではないぞ！

Is it something like this: It's not even close to paying in double?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to explain what どころ means by itself (etymologically it's somehow related to 所), but it is a kind of particle which marks something totally different from the reality. See [this dictionary entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D-583229). You would see this in one of the following forms:

> - Aどころか、Bだ。
> - Aどころではない。（むしろ/実際は/etc）Bだ。
> - Aどころの話ではない。（むしろ/実際は/etc）Bだ。
> - Aどころの騒ぎではない。（むしろ/実際は/etc）Bだ。

Aどころか forms a subordinate clause. The others can form a standalone sentence and means "Far from A", "Saying A is out of the question / severe understatement / totally wrong", etc.

This どころ(か) is used to strongly negate A in order to emphasize B. Unlike English "far from being ～", the "reality" part (B) can be either something more extreme than A or something opposite from A. In other words, A can be either a severe understatement or just plain wrong. The followings all make sense:

> - 「彼女は若いの？」「若いどころじゃないよ、彼女は2歳だ。」 (saying young is not enough...)
> - 「彼女は若いの？」「若いどころじゃないよ、彼女は100歳だ。」 (far from young ...)
> - 10万円儲けるどころか、1000万円儲かった。
> - 10万円儲けるどころか、10万円損をしてしまった。

So 倍返しどころの話ではないぞ means 倍返し (="double payback / getting you back double", a famous phrase used on a recent TV drama) is either not enough at all or totally wrong. Theoretically, a sentence that can follow would be something like むしろ10倍返しだ ("tenfold payback") or something like むしろ感謝しなければならない ("we need to thank them"), depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is:  --  (the revenge will be) much more than twice the original offense.

「やられたらやり返す。倍返しだ！」
 was used in a TV show and 「倍返しだ」
became a popular buzz-word for that year.

From:  [http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/どころでない](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

- 彼は若いどころでない He is far from young.  - 斎藤和英大辞典
- 面白いどころでない “Interesting” is no name for it.  - 斎藤和英大辞典

Similar ( or possibly-confusing ) expressions:

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17332/meaning/m0u/
>   わけがない／はずがない／べくもない／ことはない／どころではない
>
> 〔どころではない〕
>   ▽ 宿題が山ほどたまっていて、遊びに行くどころではないんです

Answer (score 0):

倍返しどころの話ではないぞ！
It's not even close to paying in double.

YES! I think your translation is correct!
どころ is used to indicate a completely different or opposite situation.
So it could mean paying much more than double... or it could be paying nothing!
What is the opposite of paying double? Without context the sentence is ambiguous.