# Meaning of とすればの話だが

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, conditionals

> ピーブズよりやっかいなのは...そんなのがいるとすれば**の話だが**...管理人のアーグスフィルチだった。
> The thing that was a bigger nuisance than Peeves...if there was such a thing... was the caretaker, Argus Filch.

I'm struggling to understand what の話だが does in this sentence. It seems to me to be perfectly grammatical, and makes sense, without it.

そんなのがいるとすれば = "If we consider such a thing to exist".

In the grammar I know you can't add anything on to ば so I'm guessing とすればの話だが is some kind of set phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とすればの話だが may not be a set phrase, but の話 is a versatile phrase used like so:

- もしもの話だが、…
  Hypothetically speaking, ...
- ここだけの話だが、…
  This is just between you and me, but ...
- いつかの話ですけど、旅行に行きたいですね。
  It's not for now, but I'd like to go on a trip.
- 全部覚えればいいだけの話だ。
  All you have to do is remember them all.
- それを買ってからの話です。
  That's something to consider after the purchase.
- できるできないの話ではない、やれ。
  It's not a matter of whether you can or can't. Do it.
- [～どころの話ではない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39586/5010)

This type of 話 is difficult to translate directly, but I feel the English word "matter" is close. The part before の話 is quite flexible. Xの話だが is used to provide a precondition that you want the listener to know before diving into the topic.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in thinking I can omit の話だが from this sentence, or would that make it ungrammatical/awkward somehow?

Comment: @user3856370 Having の話だが would be better than not having it. However, although this is one possible way of translating "..., if any, ..." into Japanese, it "looks translated" to me, with or without の話だが. The most natural version is simply"ピーブズよりやっかいなのがいるとすれば(それは)管理人のアーグスフィルチだった".

Comment: For what it's worth, the English is more roundabout than usual phrasing, too :) Rowling's writing style is like that a lot of the time.